# Jmail set return email address

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, jmail

I'm using Jmail 4.5 (www.dimac.net), I have set the Return-Path but if the email bounces it doesn't use the return address. It sends it back to the original sender.

```
  .AddHeader "Return-Path","email@domain.com"
```

I'm just stumped :(

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247155/463139) regarding `Return-Path`; in effect, the recipient's mail server must set it, not you.

Comment: in CDOSYS i m using myMail.sender="bounce@mywebsite.com" works fine