# Retrieve of the bounce mail in php?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpmailer

I am using swift mailer , which only provide me opition of failure mail, 
that is, indicate whether the mail delivered to outgoing mail server (not report after sending process). 
So i am finding any way to tell me whether there is bounce mail. I find zend and phpmailer BHM, the phpmailer has not updated for a while (2009) , so would zend  the best choice can help me doing this or i can do it by some coding in php? 
Thank you

Reference:

1.Zend
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/

2.phpmailer BMH
http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=bmh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process bounced messages, Zend Framework would only be helpful if you had all bounced messages go to a real mailbox somewhere, and then you could use [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html) to connect to the mailboxes, and read all of the messages and look for bounces.  Otherwise, in my opinion it doesn't have anything that would make it any easier to process bounces that you couldn't do in PHP or other libraries.

The above is certainly a good solution to this.

Alternatively, you can have all incoming mail for a particular email address piped to a PHP script (or it doesn't have to be PHP).  This script would be able to read `stdin` to get the contents of the email message.  You could then use something like [mailparse](http://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse) to parse the message into mime parts to make it easier to process the headers and messages.  Using such a parser is not required, however it would make the task of processing bounced emails easier.  To do something like that, search for [pipe mail to php](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=pipe+mail+to+php) or similar.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247155/892493) also provides some good information on which address mail servers will use to send bounces back to.

Comment: how to filter bounce message from bounce set