# Change the Return-Path in PHP mail function

Tags: email, php

Is it possible to change the Return-Path value in emails are sending via mail() function of PHP ?

It's value is 'www-data@mydomain.com' in emails I send in my site and it causes some problems on email delivery failed process. I want to set it to my email address.

Here's the code I have tried:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: <adminemail@yahoo.com>"."\n";
$headers .= "Errors-To: <adminemail@yahoo.com>"."\n";
// Additional headers
$headers .= "To: email1@yahoo.com <adminemail@yahoo.com>" . "\n";
$headers .= "From: adminemail@yahoo.com <adminemail@yahoo.com>";
// Mail it
mail('email1@yahoo.com', 'test', 'salam', $headers, "f");
```

Answer (score 48):

You can set reply to & return path into headers as below

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Return-Path: webmaster@example.com'
```

OR
as the fifth parameter to adjust the return path

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f email@wherever.com");
```

where email@wherever.com should be replaced by your mail.

Comment: I try this ,but the return-path doesn't change. I check the full-header of recieve mail and it is still the same.

Comment: Try to place space after -f and check. "-f email@gmail.com"

Comment: I think `\r\n` needs to be in double quotes, not single.

Comment: The -f option worked for me. Setting the Return-Path header (as I was trying before arriving on this answer) was not working, it was overridden by the system.

Comment: In my case `-femail@wherever.com` working just fine without any space or anything.

Comment: I think it's considered incorrect to set the Return-Path header. The Receiving MTA sets the Return-Path based on the Envelope.From. PHPMailer stopped allowing the Return-Path to be set in the message headers for that reason. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247155/450127

Comment: In my case adding header `Return-Path: sender@domain.com` did not helped. In sent email was still incorrect e.g. `domain.com@serverhostname.com` instead of `sender@domain.com` so SPF verification failed `Received-SPF: None`. But adding 5th argument `-f sender@domain.com` helped and Return-Path is correctly set to `sender@domain.com` and SPF is OK `Received-SPF: Pass`.

Answer (score 6):

Just define Return-Path

```php
$returnPath = "-fadminemail@yahoo.com"; //-f will do the job
mail('email1@yahoo.com', 'test', 'salam', $headers, $returnPath);
```

Comment: Note that fore better readability you can use space `-f adminemail@yahoo.com`

Answer (score 4):

The issue is mail format requires headers to use `\r\n` line endings... not `\n`, the trick with that is some servers will accept both (convert them for you and it seems to work magically) while others will consider those without `\r\n` endings to be invalid and basically ignore all your headers.  So try instead:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n".
   "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n".
   "Return-Path: adminemail@yahoo.com";
mail ("email1@yahoo.com","test","salam",$headers);
```

By the way, return-path expects an RFC1123 mailbox (without the angle brackets, just the email address) ... not sure why you'd want to set return-path as in your example since it's the same as the from address (so superfluous)

Comment: This just saved my day.  My return path was being ignored and defaulting back to www-data.. changed to from `\n` to `\r\n` and it's working as expected.

Comment: -1 Because this doesn't answer the question and gives non-working code. You have a random `"f"` as the last parameter for `mail()`. There is an `-f` flag. Just inputting `f` is a mistake.

Comment: In my case adding header `Return-Path: sender@domain.com` did not helped. In sent email was still incorrect e.g. `domain.com@serverhostname.com` instead of `sender@domain.com` so SPF verification failed `Received-SPF: None`. But adding 5th argument `-f sender@domain.com` helped and Return-Path is correctly set to `sender@domain.com` and SPF is OK `Received-SPF: Pass`.