# What are the ways to set Return-Path in the emails thats being sent out via .NET?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, smtpclient

I am facing lot of issues with my current email system that being implemented in our application. There are lot of emails that are going out of the application and bounces back. Here my Return-Path set is by default which is the from address.

How can i set Return-Path to bounce@xxx.com? I tried to set the same in the headers, but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to do is set both the Sender and the From properties on the MailMessage object.  The Sender property should be the address where you want bounce messages and the From property should be the address where you want the messages to appear from (in the case of successful delivery).

Comment: If i set sender, it will show "From X@Y.COM on behalf of A@B.COM", i dnt want something like that...

Comment: Please see the answer in this thread.  The Return-Path is set by the recipients mail server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235534/what-is-the-behavior-difference-between-return-path-reply-to-and-from

Comment: what ever emails that are being sent out bounces back if in case of no recipient. In this case, i wanna redirect all the mails to one of the system, that is bounce@company.com