# How to Get Bounce List of an Email Campaign using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having problem.when i send emails to some client all are send but if client mailbox could be busy or not available that time mail is bounced,so i want that bounce email list of sended mails and also want the solution of open rate and read rate.

Comment: You probably want to set either the reply-to or return-path, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235534/what-is-the-behavior-difference-between-return-path-reply-to-and-from first.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to configure email messages instead of about programming.

Answer (score 1):

what have you specified the reply address as?

You will need to specify the reply address so that any bounced emails will return to a mail box/exchange on your side and not the clients.