# Receive bounced email errors to a specific email address

Tags: email, plone

How is it possible, using `MailHost.send()`, to send an email from `me@example.com` and if there is a bounce error it will not be sent to `me@example.com` but to `error@example.com`?

I have tried with headers like `Return-Path` but no success.

Comment: You cannot affect the `Return-Path:` header on the receiving end; it gets replaced by the envelope sender by the receiving MTA, so anything you put there will be overwritten. Instead, you should be setting the envelope sender (the SMTP `MAIL FROM:<>` address), which is independent from the headers. If you have `sendmail` or a compatible underneath, its `-f` option is the ticket.

Comment: What tripleee says. The `MailHost.send()` function equivalent is to use the bounce receiving email as the `from` address, and use the `me@example.com` email only in the email itself as the `From:` header.

Comment: Ick, except it looks as if `MailHost` explicitly replaces the `From` header if you also set the `mfrom` keyword argument in the `send()` method.

Comment: @Martin : yes, I have tried this too... the `mfrom` replaces the `From` header...

Comment: Take a look at this answer on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1247155/722135

Answer (score 1):

I think instead you can verify if the email address exists & is valid in the first place & route the mail accordingly, I found these options which provide an API for verifying valid Email addresses

1 - [Mashape](https://www.mashape.com/pozzad/email-validator-1#!)
2 - [Free Email Verifier](http://verify-email.org/using-api.html)
3 - [Swift Email Verifer](http://www.webemailverifier.com/api.htm)
4 - [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/)

Hope one of those links help you out

Comment: That will eventually works for non valid emails. But for emails with errors like full mailbox,etc... this will no work.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 headers you can use:

Sender - Address of the actual sender acting on behalf of the author listed in the From: field

Error-To - Indicates where error messages should be sent. In the absence of this line, they go to the Sender