# What e-mail address from header will be used when answering by holiday message?

Tags: php, email

I have corresponding problem. I'm sending newsletters by PHP scripts. E-mail's headers are :

```
Return-Path: <no-reply@vojta.cz>
From : No Reply <no-reply@vojta.cz>
Reply-To : Vojtech Tuma <me@vojta.cz>
```

What heppen if this e-mail is sent to mailbox where is set auto-answer (I'm on vacation blah blah...) Which address from header will be used for auto-anser as "To" header parametr ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235534/what-is-the-behavior-difference-between-return-path-reply-to-and-from

Comment: I have already read that article. But it isn't exactly solving my problem. I don't know if auto-answer is made by server or client side. If it be only on server side I hope that Return-Path should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the receiver's email client is configured.  If their client is configured to ignore Reply-To, it will get sent to no-reply@vojta.cz, otherwise it will send to me@vojta.cz.

You literally have no control over this.

Comment: Thanks. So must address no-reply@vojta.cz exists ? I have about 900 different domains, which are using the newsletter.

Comment: Only if you care about what email goes to it.  If you don't care, it really doesn't matter if it bounces.

I suspect out-of-office messages belong to the "I don't care" category.

Answer (score 0):

When you get an Auto Answer You'll get the following headers:
X-Autoreply: yes
Auto-Submitted: auto-replied

Standard wise It'll go back to the **Reply-To** e-mail.

Please check [RFC-3834 - Recommendations for Automatic Responses to Electronic Mail](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3834) Item 3.1.2 .

Comment: It will require to read incomig messages in "no-reply@vojta.cz" mailbox? I just want to throw away automated answers, but kept the option to answer on newsletter in mail client by clicking "Reply" button.