# exchange, forward emails using reply to from original message

Tags: email, exchange-server, reply

I have Microsoft Exchange:

We use a main company email (main@domain.com) to send mail on behalf of users (user@gmail/Hotmail/own .com):

User sends an email to another user, our system sends the message as main@domain.com and then uses the senders own e-mail as the reply to.

If the message doesn't go through a bounce message is sent from the destination server, however the bounce message is sent to main@domain.com (FROM).

We want the bounce message to go to the users mailbox so they know it is incorrect or there is something wrong and it wasn't delivered.

Is there a way to do this? To read through the original email info and see who the reply to is and forward to that email address?

If we can't do it as a macro can we forward all mail sent to: mail@domain.com to a script and have the script handle the parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Reply-To and Return-Path headers and set that to the address you want then the DSN should go to users Mailbox. DSN's can be produced at different points of the delivery of an Email so it really depends on the recipients system. There a good explanation in [What is the behavior difference between return-path, reply-to and from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235534/what-is-the-behavior-difference-between-return-path-reply-to-and-from)

Cheers
Glen