# How to set Return-Path correctly in PHP?

Tags: php, email

I send emails from PHP and they are very often spam-filtered.

Therefore I try to use the Return-Path header:

```
<?
     $headers .= "Return-Path: ".$return_path."\r\n"; 
?>
```

The problem is that I have to use the same software on several servers thus have to find out the correct value within PHP.

AFAIK the return path must include the reverse DNS name from the server it is currently running and an existing username.

Comment: The server will usually set a correct Return-Path for you.  Are you using an SMTP server for sending mail?  Is the "From:" email address a real and valid email address that can receive mail?

Comment: I use the PHP mail() function and exim

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect, the Return-Path while sending an e-mail is an e-mailaddress to which  a receiving server can send fault codes or messages in case of an error / problem. Read this topic on [email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235534/what-is-the-behavior-difference-between-return-path-reply-to-and-from)

If you want to automatically fill the return path with an e-mailadres corresponding to the site you are using, use something like:

```
$return_path = 'info@'.str_replace('www.','',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: Yes, but the return-path must point to the actual server that sends the message, otherwise the spam filter thinks you want to disguise your identity.

Comment: where have you aquired this wisdom? This is true for the FROM field, but to my knowledge it is not for the return-path. However, u have use of the `$_SERVER` var, and within it, you will see `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` where you will have the host of the site running the file.

Comment: I know for sure that it's not true for the form field - in fact I need to send mail where this is exactly not true. I don't know about the return-path, as I get contradictory information...