Sending bounced mail to specific mail address using Microsoft Graph API in ASP.NET C#?
When sending a mail if the mail gets failed/bounced, those failed/bounced back mail needs to be delivered to the specific mentioned mail address instead of from address using Microsoft Graph API in ASP.NET C#.
I tried to add bounce mail address but in Microsoft Graph there was no option to enter bounced mail address.
----This is the code I used to send bounced mail to specific address(bouncemail@email.com) using ChilKat. How to achieve this using Microsoft Graph API in asp.net core -----
     Chilkat.Email mail = new Chilkat.Email();
     mail.From = "abcdef@email.com";
     mail.AddTo("", "abc@email.com");
     mail.BounceAddress = "bouncemail@email.com";
     mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
     mail.Body = "This is a Test Message";
     MailMan mman = new MailMan();
     mman.SmtpHost = "smtp.office365.com";
     mman.SmtpPort = 587;
     mman.SmtpUsername = "abcdef@email.com";
     mman.SmtpPassword = "******";
     bool mailSend = mman.SendEmail(mail);
     if (mailSend == true)
         Console.WriteLine("Message Sent Succesfully");
     else
         Console.WriteLine(mman.LastErrorText.ToString());

--This is code used for Microsoft Graph API. How to add bounce mail address (like mail.BounceAddress="bouncemail@email.com" in Chilkat) for the below code--
            ClientSecretCredential credential = new(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new(credential);
            var requestBody = new SendMailPostRequestBody
            {
                Message = new Message
                {
                    Subject = MailSubject,
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                        Content = MailContent,
                    },
                    From = new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = FromMailID } },
                    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
                        {
                        new Recipient
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                            {
                                Address = ToMailID,
                            },
                        },
                        },
                },
                SaveToSentItems = true                    
            };
           await GraphClient.Me.SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
           Console.WriteLine("Mail Sent Successfully");


Are you trying to send phishing emails or spam?

No... I just need to send a email but when recipient mail address is invalid it usually bounced back a mail to the sender. Instead sending those bounced mail to sender it needs to be sent to specific mail address(given mail id)

What your talking about is the Return-Path property of a Message which is used to Send NDR's to. While it's valid to have a different Return-Path and is something desirable for Mailing list the RFC states https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2821 states
   A message-originating SMTP system SHOULD NOT send a message that
   already contains a Return-path header.  SMTP servers performing a
   relay function MUST NOT inspect the message data, and especially not
   to the extent needed to determine if Return-path headers are present.
   SMTP servers making final delivery MAY remove Return-path headers
   before adding their own

So to be compliant the Graph shouldn't allow you to do this, what should end up in the Return-Path is the (Envelope) P1 'Mail From' header. So if you really need to do that you'll need to look at using SMTP.

Kindly look into the question which I have edited with code I m using it

https://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_59.asp the bonceaddress is just effectivity setting the Return-Path header. Without seeing a protocol capture it's probably just using the envelope headers. The Graph doesn't support this even if you send as MIME and set that header it will be removed in the Transport pipeline as the Graph uses the Mailbox database Submission service (high layer of abstraction).  If you need to set that you need to be working at that lower SMTP layer also ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235534/what-is-the-behavior-difference-between-return-path-reply-to-and-from
